# How many equivalence classes are there in $S$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $S$ be the set of all $2 × 3$ real matrices each of whose entries is $1, 0,$ or $−1.$ (There are $36$ matrices in $S.$)
Recall that the column space of a matrix $M$ in $S$ is the subspace of $R^
2$
(the vector space of $2×1$ real matrices)
spanned by the three columns of $M.$ For two elements $M$ and $M'$
in $S$, let us write $M ∼ M'$
if $ M$ and $M'$
have the same column space. Note that $∼$ is an equivalence relation. How many equivalence classes are
there in $S$?

Doubt:-Is the number of equivalence classes the same as the number of Subaspaces of dimension $1$ or $2$?
I used this formula:
Here [Number of $k$-dimensional subspaces in $V$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600432/number-of-k-dimensional-subspaces-in-v)

$|V|=2$ and $|F|=q=3$ $k=1,2$. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: I think there are $3^6$ matrices in $S$, not $36$. Also, that counting-subspaces-post probably isn't going to help you, as that's specifically for vector spaces over finite fields, while you have vector spaces over what seems to be $\Bbb R$.

Comment: But Answer given is that $6$.

Comment: @Mathgeek Counting the number of *matrices* in $S$ is not the same as the number of *equivalence classes*.  While there may be $6$ equivalence classes (*I haven't bothered trying to solve this yet*), the number of *matrices* in your set can be found quite easily using introductory counting techniques using in particular the rule of product.  For each unknown, count how many options there are.  Multiply the number of unknowns for each step together.  So, pick the first row first column entry, there are three options.  Then pick the first row second column entry, again 3 options, so on so forth

Comment: The subspaces are 0,$\mathbb{R}^2$,$\langle(1,0)\rangle$,$\langle(0,1)\rangle$,$\langle(1,1)\rangle$,$\langle(1,-1)\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

The only column vectors that it is possible to get in the matrix are $a=(0,0),b=(1,0),c=(0,1)$, $d=(1,1),e=(-1,1)$ or one of these times -1. If all the entries are $a$, then we get the subspace 0. If we have both $b$ and $c$, then we get $\mathbb{R}^2$. If we have nothing but $a,b,-b$ then we get $\langle(1,0)\rangle$. If we have nothing but $a,c,-c$ we get $\langle(0,1)\rangle$. If we have nothing but $a,\pm d$ we get $\langle(1,1)\rangle$. If we have nothing but $a,\pm e$ we get $\langle(-1,1)\rangle$. Other combinations (like $b$ and $d$) give us $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is easy to see there are no other possibilities. So we have 6 equivalence classes.